# Implementing getchar issue in C

Tags: c

I'm implementing `getchar()`, I have two issues with the `BUFF_SIZE`, when I use `1024` my `getchar()` reads all the characters and return one character discards the rest. This doesn't work inside a loop.

```
#ifndef BUFF_SIZE
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#endif

int my_getchar(void)
{
    static char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    static char *chr;
    int         ret;

    if ((ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
    {
        chr = buff;
        return (*chr);
    }
    return (EOF);
}

int get_line(char **line)
{
    char *text = malloc(sizeof(char) * 4092);
    int position = 0;
    int c;
    if (!text)
        return (-1);
    while (1)
    {
        c = my_getchar();
        if (c == EOF || c == '\n')
        {
            text[position] = '\0';
            *line = text;
            return (1);
        }
        else
            text[position] = c;
        position++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

When I set `BUFF_SIZE` to `1`, it works fine inside a loop, and doesn't work well outside a loop. How can I solve this?

```
int main()
{
    //comment out to test.
    //char  *sp;

    //sp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4092);
    //get_line(&sp); // this function calls my_getchar inside a while loop.
    printf("%c\n", my_getchar()); //calling my_getchar() outside a loop
    // printf("%s\n", sp);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: What does "doesn't work well outside a loop" mean?

Comment: see the screenshot, it return the first character and the rest are regarded as a command.

Comment: What do you expect `read` to do? That's where your problem and answer is.

Comment: I took your code as posted, and `#define`d macro `BUFF_SIZE` to `1`.  I added the necessary header inclusions and a `main()` function.  It does not exhibit the "doesn't work well outside a loop" behavior you describe.  Nor would I expect it to do.

Comment: read() attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd
       into the buffer starting at buf.
 It is
       not an error if this number is smaller than the number of bytes
       requested; this may happen for example because fewer bytes are
       actually available right now - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html -

Comment: When calling any of the memory allocation function: (malloc, calloc, realloc), 1) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  2) the expression: `sizeof( char )` is defined in the C standard as ALWAYS=1,  multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  So the expression in the parameter to `malloc()` has no effect, just clutters the code, making the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the 'real' function: `getchar()` 1) returns an `int`, not a `char`.  This is mostly because `EOF` is an `int`.  2) does not consume all the available input from stdin, rather it only consume 1 keystroke   The `my_getchar()` is returning everything, up to  BUFF_SIZE keystrokes.  To be a replacement for `getchar()`, those two problems need to be fixed

Comment: the returned type from the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc) has type `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting the returned value just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: the function: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not a `int`

Comment: the parameter to `get_line()` is a `char**` (it really only needs to be a `char*`)  Then this line: `*line = text;` is only dereferencing once, so it changing where the resulting pointer points.  Not what you want to do.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("%c\n", my_getchar());` Since `getchar()` returns an `int`, then `my_getchar()` should also return an `int`, so the line should be: `printf("%c\n", (char)my_getchar());`

Comment: the posted question indicates that the user, you, entered `ello` on a new prompt.  Of course that does not work as there is no program named: `ello`

Comment: @user3629249 I entered `hello` and `my_getchar` returned `h` and discarded `ello`

Comment: then why is their a 'ello' in your posted output?

Comment: @user3629249 That is the discarded output, being executed as a command, when I use `BUFF_SIZE` set to 1, in `my_getchar()`.

Comment: the code is NOT outputting the 'discarded' input.  So the posted output is not all from the posted code.

Comment: @user3629249 set `BUFF_SIZE` to `1`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is issue in your `my_getchar` function. Issue is here:

```
/* When you do return *char only first char is returned */
if ((ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
{
    chr = buff;
    return (*chr); 
}
```

There you are doing `return (*chr);` you return only the first `char` in `buff`, so that way a `\n` is not returned and so your `get_line` is affected as it depends on a `\n` returned. This can be fixed this by adding an additional static variable to track the position of latest char returned, as below.

```
int my_getchar(void)
{
    static char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    static char *chr;
    static int pos = 0;  /* New static variable to track position */
    static int ret = 0;  /* Changed this to static */

    if (pos >= ret) { /* if all data in buffer has been returned */
            if ((ret = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE)) > 0)
            {
                    chr = buff;
                    pos = 0;
                    return *(chr + pos++); /* return one char and update pos */
            } else {  /* if no more to read from stdin */
                    return EOF;
            }
    } else { /* if data still in buffer */
            return *(chr + pos++); /* return one char and update pos */
    }
}
```

Now, `my_getchar` will return a `\n` when `pos` reaches the postition of `\n` in the buffer, so `get_line` will get all characters before the new line character.

Answer (score 0):

Your `my_getchar()` skips `BUF_SIZE - 1` characters on each invokation. Every time you call it - it reads `BUF_SIZE` characters from `stdin` (or less if we are at the end of the file) and returns the first character. All other are dropped, because when you call it next time it reads `BUF_SIZE` chars again instead of returning of the next char from previously read buffer.

Comment: @4386427 I know, my question is how, can I deal with this two issues, When I set buffer to `1`, `my_getchar()` works inside a loop and doesn't work when I use it outside a loop. And when I set buffer to `1024` the function works outside a loop but not inside.

Answer (score 0):

When you set BUFF_SIZE to 1, you are calling read like this:

```
 read(STDIN, buff, 1)
```

But, since STDIN is connected to a terminal, read() is allowed to wait for a line to be typed in before returning the first character.  So, the function is behaving correctly (as written).

The good news is that if you use `printf("%c\n", getchar());`, you will see that getchar() behaves in the same way.

The main problem with your version is that it is built on top of `read()` -- the real `getchar()` is in `<stdio.h>` and meant to be mixable with the calls in there that use `FILE*` and its buffering.  So, unless you are reimplementing all of `stdio`, it probably makes sense to build it on its primitives (e.g. `fread`).

If you are reimplementing all of `<stdio>`, then you should be implementing some equivalent to `FILE`, which is where the buffers would live (not in static variables inside of functions).

Comment: I am fairly confident that the buffering you describe is a characteristic of the `stdin` *stream* and the standard I/O functions around streams, not of the underlying file descriptor and POSIX I/O functions.

Comment: @Lou No it doesn't.

Comment: I think we agree @JohnBollinger -- I am suggesting that getchar should act as if it's using the stdin stream (and its buffers).  getchar()'s doc says it's getc(FILE*) with the arg set to stdin.

Comment: @TenTenPeter Can you elaborate? What doesn't?

Comment: @TenTenPeter - what compiler? what OS?  I am using gcc on OSX.

Comment: @LouFranco I'm using `Fedora 24` gcc `v6`

Comment: If you want to make my_getchar() that acts like getchar(), use fread instead of read.

Answer (score 0):

OP's code reads `BUFF_SIZE` `char`s, and returns only 1.

Need to *selectively* read.  Only read when previous characters are comsumed.

Note: Better to pass in a structure pointer to the *state* (`buff, index,count`) than to use `static` variables, but staying with OP's approach:

```
int my_getchar(void) {
    static unsigned char buff[BUFF_SIZE];
    static int index = 0;
    static int count = 0;

    if (index >= count) {
      index = 0;
      count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
      if (count == 0) return EOF;  // end-of-file
      if (count < 0) return EOF;  // I/O error
    }
    return buff[index++];
  }
```

Note: important to read an `unsigned char` buffer to distinguish `EOF` from input charterers.

Depending on `STDIN_FILENO` attributes, a return value of 0 from `read()` may simple imply input not presently available.  Then use

```
      // count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
      // if (count == 0) return EOF;  // end-of-file
      do {
        count = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE);
      } while (count == 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code reads as many characters as possible:

```
read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFF_SIZE)
```

up to `BUFF_SIZE` and then only returns the first character.

For that to work as intended, your buffer size needs to be 1.

Comment: I want to implement `getchar` that will work inside and outside a loop.